# JavaScript: Как написать модальное окно?

Tags: javascript

Помогите написать модальное окно, которое будет выводить текст. Проблема в том, что модальное окно должно быть написано на чистом js (без использования html или css). Только js. Окно должно появляться, когда я получаю message.

```
(function ($) {
      async function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.data.messageType === 'CLIENT_MESSAGE') {
          console.log("MESSAGE", event);
          (тут должно быть модальное окно)
        }
      }
 $(document).ready(function () {    
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
   
  });
```

Все примеры, что я смотрела, всё равно содержат немного html, но мне нужно, чтобы использовался только js.

Comment: тебе с помощью js нужно создавать html или как? просто без html ты это не сделаешь, JS нечего будет отрисовывать

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: самое модальное: `alert(text)`

Comment: ну alert не подходит.  мне нужно чтоб выводило  сообщение об успешной операции. Пусть не модельное. Может есть какае-та функция DOM которая выводит сообщение в центре экрана

Comment: @АннаМороз, а что не так с выводом сообщения об успешной операции с помощью `alert`?

Comment: Можно и с помощью Js создавать html. Да это может сработать. Просто не могу сообразить как лучше сделать(

Answer (score 0):

Если сложно сделать самостоятельно, то можно использовать готовые решения. Например вот модальное окно с фреймворком Bootstrap 4.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5 ml-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Запустить модальное окно
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Документация по Bootstrap 4](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

[Модальное окно Bootstrap 4](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.5/components/modal/)

Comment: Как по мне нужно научиться разбираться в простых вещах и только потом юзать фреймворки, библиотеки и прочее.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, не спорю.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelector('#open'),
        modal = document.querySelector('#modal'),
        closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close');

openBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
});

window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    if (target === modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```css
.myModal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    min-height: 170px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 750px;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  
  @keyframes animatetop {
    from {
      top: -300px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      top: 0;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  /* The Close Button */
  #close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }
  
  #close:hover,
  #close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    background-color: #339af0;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 2px 10px;
  }
  
  .warning-icon {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  
  .message {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
   <button id="open">Open</button>
    <div id="modal" class="myModal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="close" data-close>&times;</div>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Message</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="warning-icon" src="https://icon-library.com/images/successful-icon/successful-icon-10.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="message">Registration successful!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```